SQL Updating a table column from first 9 digits of another column
I have a USER table with SSN in one column and SSN +5 digits (lets just call SSNPLUS) in another column. The source for SSN has become corrupted for some rows, so I would like to update the SSN from part of the other column only for those impacted rows.
Example Problem
SSN       SSNPLUS
012345678 01234567899221   <--this is valid
888888888 88888888854221   <--this is valid
56ABCJ    07512333800998   <--SSN col is invalid because of alpha chars
992345678 99234567877112   <--this is valid
81AJUNK   01526690966772   <--SSN col is invalid because of alpha chars 
098765432 09876543288992   <--this is valid

Desired Result

SSN       SSNPLUS
012345678 01234567899221   
888888888 88888888854221   
075123338 07512333800998   
992345678 99234567877112   
015266909 01526690966772    
098765432 09876543288992   

In some kind of psudo-speak, I think i want to do is something like this:
update USER set USER.ssn select left(ssnplus, 9) from USER.ssnplus where ssn contains [A-Z]

You can see I am not an SQL person and part of me wants to throw a regex in there but i'm guessing that does not work in this application; any help is greatly appreciated as our DB guy hasn't been replaced yet! Ugh!

most commands depend on the database server version please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms and edit your question

What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

The DB we are using is Oracle DB

The following SQL should work in most RDBMS's:
UPDATE USER 
  SET ssn = LEFT(ssnplus, 9)
WHERE ssn <> LEFT(ssnplus, 9)
;


perfect, thank you for that simple but elegant answer!
